# Strange Behaviour in db2 9.7 Fix Pak 0

Tags: db2-luw

I have two windows machines one with

```
  1. db2 9.7 on FP 1 (Lets call it A) and
  2. Another machine with db2 9.7 on FP 0 (Lets call it B)
```

Both the machines are getting connection through same Driver -> db2jcc-9.7.jar

I am trying to add a column 'COL' to an existing table 'TAB'
SQL -> ALTER TABLE TAB ADD COLUMN COL INTEGER NULL;

**The above sql is working fine in A**

But giving error in B

> Error Message -> DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it returned:
>   SQL0104N  An unexpected token "END-OF-STATEMENT" was found following "COUNTER 
>   INTEGER NULL".  Expected tokens may include:  "".
>   SQLSTATE=42601

What might be the reason for this behaviour?

`Note: The DB2_COMPATIBILITY_VECTOR parameter has not been set in both the databases.`

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: The error message does not seem to fit the ALTER TABLE statement. Why is the token "COUNTER INTEGER NULL" in there? From where do you execute the statement?

Comment: I have executed the above sql statement from db2 command prompt, after establishing the connection to the database. As per the "COUNTER INTEGER NULL" message, I am also blank about it.